# Using node/express to do scheduled backend work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a MEAN stack application. Website and API to access mongo. Aswell as these two I need to be able to do some scheduled backend work to populate the database (get a gip/gzip from url, read through the data and push into the DB).

Is express/node the right approach to do this with or is there an alternative? Also, would this lie as a seperate application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need on node instance running if you are managing the calling yourself. Or you could use some service that would do scheduling for you. There are serveral on heroku.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

if you want to do it yourself, then you can easily do it using this library.

Just put time or day in the parameter in this order `(Seconds Minutes Hours MonthDays Month WeekDays)` and pass the function you want it to call then.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my user website/api services as a separate instance from the service that runs my scheduled tasks. Although my scheduled task service does have API's for configuring tasks (new, edit, delete, start, stop, etc).

For scheduling, I am a big fan of node-schedule.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule